# Prevent Browser Timeout When Receiving Large Amounts Of Data

Tags: html, browser, timeout

I have an administrative interface that is used by one of my clients that, when a process is initiated through a web interface, the server processes a massive amount of records on the backend server.  The web page then provides updates using just simple HTML (not any AJAX or other JS) updates and looks like this:

```
Processing All Records: 
000000 to 000099: ....................................................................................................
000100 to 000199: ....................................................................................................
//... More Records Processed Here ...
009700 to 009799: ....................................................................................................
009800 to 009899: ..............................
Data processing complete: 9830 total records processed
```

This processing can take upwards of an hour.  In the browsers I use (IE and Crome), the page continues receiving the updates and displaying them as they are processed.  **The problem is** that, for my client (using multiple browsers and computers), his screen stops displaying the updates after a few mintutes, and even if he waits until the processing is supposed to be complete (leaving his browser open overnight), that he never receives the "Data processing complete" notification.  Basically, his browser simply times out, even thought the processing continues on the server and the process does complete.

The HTML output (using classic ASP... I know, ugg) is done with a simple `Response.Write(".")` after each record is processed.  Other than a standard HTML `<head>` `</head>` `<body>` `</body>` tags, no other formatting is applied and all the Response.Writes are done within the body (so the browser isn't waiting for any closing tag other than the body tag).

I realize that I could rewrite the code and use some fancy JS and AJAX calls for updates, or move to an asynchronous service with email updates, but I want to find the simplest solution that doesn't require me to change the code much.

So, my question is, **what setting in his browser/network would cause his browser to time out while all the browsers I tested continue to receive the data**?

If it helps, here is the raw HTML that is output:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\css\normal.css">
</head>
<body>
Initiating data retreival at: 8/23/2012 11:02:59 AM<br>
<hr>
Processing All Records: 
<br>000000 to 000099:....................................................................................................
<br>000100 to 000199:....................................................................................................
<br>000200 to 000299:....................................................................................................
<!-- More Lines Here -->
<br>009800 to 009899:..............................<hr>
Data import complete: 9830 total records processed<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers depends on RAM and Shared Memory regarding caching. Try your code to limited width and height, table-based

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed'>
```

This will allow the browser to render the table without it trying to recompute the width on each new row addition

Also, GTK based browsers would help you for your purpose # for example, juniper-browser, NetFront etc.

Comment: Thanks Mahbubr, but I'm not using any tables at all.  Do you think by adding a table, it will help?

Comment: And you are building an administrative interface, here you would better to use GTK based (CLI SAPI) application and browsers. Because here with CLI SAPI based applications, you don't need to rely on Web Server's restrictions. No max time limit and no memory limitation, and also you can depend on long running multi threaded applications with better shared memory support.

Comment: There are old problems with unclosed tables not causing a relayout but I can't recall a situation where it reset the browser timeout for the HTTP connection.

Comment: I added the table and we'll see if helps my client perform the update.  The only thing I noticed is that with the table, it doesn't update the "." after each record.  Instead, it waits until it has received the closing table table.

Comment: Styling has nothing to do with timeouts

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable, well-defined way of doing this because it is completely up to the browser, network connection, router, operating system, ...  Instead of hoping you strike it lucky, take control of the circumstances.

The easiest way is to refactor out one script that does the processing for a small batch of items and then keep fetching that script with AJAX (keeping an offset) until it reports that it has completed. This is more robust and well-defined than hoping to find some magic technique that, for all you know, might change in the future.